# RC integrator: why does it convert a triangular wave into a sine wave?

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrator

The output voltage of an RC integrator circuit is proportional to the integral of the input voltage.

This means that a triangular wave should transform into a quadratic curve (since the integral of a linear function is a parabola).

Why does it convert a triangular wave into a sine wave then? What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Please include a schematic.  Part values and the triangle wave frequency would help, too, because an RC circuit isn't a pure integrator -- it's a low-pass filter.

Comment: It converts a triangle wave into a parabolic wave, which is "close enough" to a sine wave.

Comment: get glasses, and look closer. Output may *appear* sinusoidal - but it isn't. Doing a Fourier transform on the output will show some harmonic content.

Comment: You can also view this as a low-pass filter. The more integrators you put in series, the better the high frequencies are filtered out, and the more the lowest one dominates.

Comment: To add some color to the "low-pass filter" comments: the square and triangle waveforms can be analyzed as the sum of many different pure sine and cosine waves with varying amplitudes.  Removing the higher-frequency components gets you closer to the single sine wave with the fundamental frequency of the input.

Comment: Any non-sinusoidal signal is composed out of multiple sinusoidal signals in superposition (harmonics). The more you filter those harmonics away with low pass filters the closer you get to the fundamental sinewave.

Comment: both of those graphs (triangle and sine) are pretty poor approximations of what the signal will actually look like at the indicated test points.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, a square wave has harmonics at all odd multiples of the fundamental, with strength diminishing as the number of the harmonic:

$$x_s(t) \simeq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\cos 2 \pi (2n + 1) t}{2n + 1}$$

A triangle wave is just the square wave, integrated, with the appropriate constant added to make things tidy:

$$x_\Delta(t) \simeq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{\sin 2 \pi (2n + 1) t}{(2n + 1)^2}$$

A parabolic wave is the same thing, again:

$$x_p(t) \simeq \sum_{n = 0}^\infty -\frac{\cos 2 \pi (2n + 1) t}{(2n + 1)^3}$$

Because of that cubic in the denominator, the difference between a sine wave and this "pseudo-sine" wave is very small.  And it turns out that it's pretty hard to see the deviation on a graph anyway.

If you plot the quadratic pseudo-sine wave on a graph, superimposed on a *real* sine wave, you'll see the (slight) difference.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't. It converts a triangle wave into a parabolic wave, which is "close enough" to a sine wave. The image you provided is making an approximation.

That said, an RC circuit isn't an integrator, but a low-pass filter. The two are similar, but not identical.

Comment: Well to be fair, after the pole, and RC LP behaves just like an integrator. If the triangular wave in the picture is out of band enough, you will get a sinusoidal wave.

Comment: I agree with @Hearth: These circuits ARE NOT integrators, whichever close to an integration operation could be the relationship between input and output. Naming things with wrong names can lead only to confusion.